# Notepad++ Save Session equivalent in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, notepad++

In Notepad++ there is an option called 'Save session' that saves a list of all opened files (in the current window), bookmarks, code foldings, cursor position, etc., so I can reopen that state later even if I close the files.

In Visual Studio Code, I have not found an option like that. It seems the Workspace only saves the folder path and some settings defined to that workspace.

Is there a way to create something like a Notepadd++ session in Visual Studio Code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the most similar thing to what you are asking for are [*Workspaces*](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/workspaces).  From testing, they do in fact keep the files you had open, so long as you *close* the workspace in the menu first.

> A Visual Studio Code "workspace" is the collection of one or more folders that are opened in a VS Code window (instance). In most cases, you will have a single folder opened as the workspace but, depending on your development workflow, you can include more than one folder, using an advanced configuration called [Multi-root workspaces](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/workspaces#_multiroot-workspaces).

> The concept of a workspace enables VS Code to:
>
> - Configure settings that only apply to a specific folder or folders but not others.
> - Persist task and debugger launch configurations that are only valid in the context of that workspace.
> - **Store and restore UI state associated with that workspace (for example, the files that are opened)**.
> - Selectively enable or disable extensions only for that workspace.

If you look under File, you'll see the Workspace options:

[image: workspaces]

The way it works is it saves a file that is a `.code-workspace` extension, but really the underlying structure is JSON.  For example, the file might look like:

```
{
    "folders": [
        {
            "path": "..\\..\\..\\..\\dev\\Project Files\\Project\\MyProject"
        }
    ],
    "settings": {}
}
```

Comment: Also, if you have a workspace open, close VSCode, and reopen, it should resume with all your files open, and where you last left off.

Comment: I've tried use workspace before. Don't seems to work very well. But as you said, I have to go on 'Close workspace' option to do the trick. It works that way. Thanks.